# Refresh the typeahead content with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The situation I have is the following:

I have a search field where the user types a text, and a webservice tries to suggest values based on the information entered so far.

My problem is that the webservice sometimes takes 2-3 seconds to generate the data, and the typeahead list is not filled in time.

```
 <form data-ng-submit="selectItem(message);">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="message" data-ng-change="handleChange(message);" data-typeahead-wait-ms="500" data-typeahead="o for o in searchOptions | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">
    <input type="submit" style="height: 0px; width: 0px; border: none; padding: 0px;" data-hidefocus="true" />
</form>
```

I could change the `typeahead-wait-ms` to 3000, but that would make the other requests very slow (the requests are normaly 100-150ms). What I would like to do is to force angularjs to redraw the typeahead options once it has the data in `$scope.searchOptions`. Is there any way to do that?

I tried to use `ng-show` (hiding and showing), tried to change the `$scope.message` (add and remove space), and nothing forced the regeneration of display so far.

**Update:**

The javascript part is as follows (there is a delay counter which calls the triggerSearch only when the search Field hasn't updated since 500msec, i removed it for simplicity):

```
var triggerSearch = function() {
    searchService.setString($scope.message); // this gives the search string to service
    $injector.get('$rootScope').$broadcast('startSearch');
};
```

then this message is listened in another controller:

```
$scope.$on('startSearch', function() {
    // here there is a $http.get which gets all the data after reading search string
    searchService.setOptions(selectionlist); // this gives back the result
    $injector.get('$rootScope').$broadcast('updatedOptions'); // calls the original controller
}
```

And then in the original controller

```
$scope.$on('updatedOptions', function() {
    $scope.searchOptions = searchService.getOptions(); // reading the list from service
    $scope.$apply(); // tried this - didnt work.
});
```

The thing is, that when I add the result of the service in a normal data on the page, it gets correctly displayed when the data becomes available, i.e. 2 seconds later. However the typeahead list is not updated.

**Update 2**

Just to be more specific about last sentence:

```
<form data-ng-submit="selectItem(message);">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="message" data-ng-change="handleChange(message);" data-typeahead-wait-ms="500" data-typeahead="o for o in searchOptions | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">
    <input type="submit" style="height: 0px; width: 0px; border: none; padding: 0px;" data-hidefocus="true" />
</form>
{{searchOptions}}
```

If I add this last line, this is correctly updated when the service has finished filling this data. It's only the typeahead which is not refreshed. So in the case above, I start typing the search substring, when the search has finished the {{searchOptions}} is correctly updated with search results.

The question is: is there any way to force the regeneration of the input field, so that the typeahead tag with the new data is taken into consideration?

Comment: Have you tried `$scope.$apply()`, are you using a `$.ajax` for the webservice call? If so, try `$http`.

Comment: The Webservice is in a different controller - I am using a shared service of the angular.module to communicate ($broadcast and $on). The webservice broadcasts a String when the data is available, and in this controller, upon receiving the broadcast, I am taking it from the service, injecting it in searchOptions.

Yes, I tried $scope.$apply, it didnt help sadly.

Comment: Post a minimal reproduce scenario, otherwise it is next to impossible to guess what is going on in your case. The typeahead can perfectly work with async data...

Comment: This is weird, because typeahead implementations always know they will be receiving their data asynchronously. Which implementation are you using?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RaUWY/1/ - created this jsfiddle (doesn't work on Chrome, no idea why, but works in FireFox). This shows the error I am having. if you type "a" in search field - you can see that 2 seconds later the list gets generated. However the typeahead choices do not appear. It looks like it's too late for it.